# How to implement a double animation in a ngRepeat? (move down the current items, fade in new item from right)

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I am trying to implement the following animation: a list of items should move down the right amount of space for a new item to be added on top (variable height), and then the new item should move in from the right.

Here is what I got: http://plnkr.co/edit/V5rrbkZgkn72OJRlXEee?p=preview

```
.list-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: table; 
}

.list-item.ng-enter,
.list-item.ng-leave
{
  -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  position: relative;
}

.list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.list-item.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.list-item.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  right: -200px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Problem is that the old list "jumps" instead of transitioning down. How do I fix this?

Comment: No animation classes are applied on rest of the items because nothing is changed there.

Comment: So what does change? I.e. what should I animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solution was to use keyframes.

```
.list-item.ng-enter {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);

  -webkit-animation: 
    openSpace 2s ease forwards, 
    moveIn 0.3s 0.2s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openSpace {
  to {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation classes applied on the added items will not be automatically added to the other items because no change happens to them, so ng-animate does not add any classes on them. Instead you could add a rule to the siblings of the currently animated one. Also update the positioning to absolute for the animated item, so that it does not push the other items down due to its current relative positioning.

Ex:-

```
.list-item.ng-enter,
.list-item.ng-leave{
  -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  position:absolute;
}

.list-item.ng-enter ~ .list-item,
.list-item.ng-leave  ~ .list-item {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
   transform:translateY(15px);
   -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all ;
  transition: 0.2s linear all ;
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', [ "ngAnimate" ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.list = [
    { id: 0, name: "TEST" },
    { id: 1, name: "aajjaja" },
    { id: 2, name: "AAAA" },
    { id: 3, name: "VVVVV" }
    ];
    
  $scope.add = function() {
     $scope.list.unshift({ id: $scope.list.length, name: "NEW ITEM" });
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.list-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: table; 
 
}

.list-item.ng-enter,
.list-item.ng-leave
{
  -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  position:absolute;
}
.list-item.ng-enter ~ .list-item,
.list-item.ng-leave  ~ .list-item {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
   transform:translateY(15px);
   -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all ;
  transition: 0.2s linear all ;
}
.list-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.list-item.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.list-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.list-item.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  right: -200px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.26"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.2.x" data-semver="1.2.26" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="add()">ADD</button>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in list">{{ item.name }}</div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not preventing the first "jump" though.. it is only translating the list after the jump (1 list item + 10px).

Comment: It is because of positioning.

Comment: See my update. You can now play around with how much you want to push and animate it based on duration.

Comment: I see, thank you. This seem a bit hacky though.. what if I do not know the height of the item that is entering the list?

Comment: I dnt know if you can animate on something witout dimension or translate.  You mustbe having some max height for the items right?

Comment: yes, I could have some max height. would that help? in fact in [this](http://css-tricks.com/transitional-interfaces-coded/) example (Brain Clue #2) it seems they set max-height to 50 but then the animation gets interrupted at 30? I don't get it.

Comment: That is because the height of the item is only so much, max-height will only ensure it does not go beyond, does not mean it will set to that height.